# Jquery submit vs. javascript submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html, submit

I am trying to invoke a form validation when clicked on ordinary button. This seems to work good with jQuery, but not with plain javascript. **Can anyone explain this difference between jquery's .submit() and javascript's .submit() methods? Or what am I doing wrong?**

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Submit</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm(form) {
  if (form.username.value=='') {
    alert('Username missing');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form action="index.php" name="loginform" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);">
  <input name="username" placeholder="username" required="required" type="text" />
  <input name="send1" type="button" value="Login1" onclick="$(document.forms.loginform).submit();" />
  <input name="send2" type="button" value="Login2" onclick="document.forms.loginform.submit();" />
  <input name="send3" type="submit" value="Login3" />
  <a href="" onclick="event.preventDefault(); $(document.forms.loginform).submit();"> Login4 </a>
  <a href="" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.forms.loginform.submit();"> Login5 </a>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: onsubmit results]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The DOM `submit()` method does not trigger submit events. jQuery's does.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanation. So the script above should be correctly extended to `if (validateForm(document.forms.loginform)) document.forms.loginform.submit();`

Comment: This is no longer the case. `document.formName.submit()` (or `document.querySelector('form[name="formName"]').submit()`) will indeed trigger a form submission

Comment: @chiliNUT — Form submission, yes. Form submit event, no.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it is not been answered very well, so here you go:

the `submit()` DOM method in vanilla javascript is used to submit a form, but the JQuery `submit()` method is used to trigger a submit event.

You need to use the submit event.

Example:

```
const form = document.querySelecor('form')
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    /* Other stuff */
})
```

OR

```
const form = document.querySelector('form')
form.onsubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    /* Other stuff */
})
```