# .submit in javascript vs .submit in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form on page. I want to submit a form when user click on submit button which is outside of form tag. When I am using `$('#theform').submit()` then submit method work perfectly but when I am doing this `document.getElementById('theform').submit()` then it is only refreshing my page.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zws59Ldc/1/)

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        //$('#theform').submit()
        document.getElementById('theform').submit()
    })

    $('#theform').submit(function(e) {
        alert(0)
        e.preventDefault()
    })
})
```

**html**

```
<form id="theform">
    <input type="text"  id="fname" />
    <input type="text"  id="lname" />
    <input type="text"  id="country" />
</form>
<input type="submit" />
```

Comment: You're not including any action in your form, how is it supposed to get submitted?

Comment: `submit()` DOM node method doesn't trigger jQuery `submit` handler, that's why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DOM submit()` method does not trigger submit events where as `jQuery's does`.that is the reason `your form` in javascript `document.getElementById('theform').submit()` will submit the `FORM`.

you can see a post here :[Jquery submit vs. javascript submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557994/jquery-submit-vs-javascript-submit)

Answer (score -3):

use   `document.forms["theform"].submit();`

and define action in your form

```
<form id="theform" action="submit-form.php">
```

Comment: `document.forms["theform"]` will return *exactly* the same DOM Element as `document.getElementById("theform")`. `getElementById` is *preferred` over `forms[]` anyway.

Comment: The key is to define an action, amit is seeing the same page because his HTML doesn't have an action in the FORM tag. Adnan consider editing your response, the way of getting the DOM element is not a problem here.