# Trigger form submission with $.submit() and prevent page reload at the same time

Tags: jquery, forms

**Please do not be too quick to mark this question as duplicate.**

I've encountered this problem. I've attached an event listener for the SUBMIT event to my form like this:

```
$('#my-form')
    .submit(function() {
        return false
     });
```

All is good, when I submit the form, there is no reload.

However, I'm also attaching another event listener to the single input field of the form like this (expanding on previous snippet):

```
$('#my-form')
    .submit(function() {
        return false
     })
    .on('keydown', function(e){
        var $form = this;
        var $actionAttr = $form.action;
        var $input = e.target;
        $form.action = $actionAttr + $input.value;
        $form.submit(); <-----      
     });
```

Now whenever I start inputting content to the text input field, the form would submit and reload the page instantly.

Is there any way to make the `submit` listener "respect" submission event fired with jQuery (`$form.submit()` in the example above).

Comment: Are you trying to post a form using ajax ? if so you have 2 options, post your form using regular post since you dont want the page to refresh. Otherwise https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery is a good project to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var $form=this;`

is problamatic. inside of a jquery event handler, `this` is the native `DOM` element, you need `$(this)` to get the jquery element. So you mean to be firing the jquery submit, but you are actually triggering the native DOM submit event, which **DOES NOT** respect event handlers. 
Just wrap your this and it should work.

[Jquery submit vs. javascript submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557994/jquery-submit-vs-javascript-submit)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('#my-form')
.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 })
.on('keydown', function(e){
    var $form = $(this);
    var $actionAttr = $form.action;
    var $input = e.target;
    $form.action = $actionAttr + $input.value;
    $form.submit();     
 });
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure these are the same in this context.

Comment: You got the issue solved by chiliNUT's answer right?